# Is LINQ to SQL possible in other languages?

Tags: c#, linq, haskell, f#, lisp

I'm interested in knowing whether something like LINQ to SQL could be possible in other languages (skip .Net), that enables to write declarative and compile-time checked queries that get translated to SQL:

- Strongly typed language
- With good support for lambdas/clousures
- Able to generate expression trees/quoting

I.E: Is it possible in Lisp, Haskell, F#, etc..?

Comment: This seems like a "list of" sort of question that is not specific enough for SO.  (the list of possible answers will be defined by the number of extant languages)

Comment: Yes, this is possible, and there are constructive proofs in the form of available code.

Comment: @Brian: "(skip .Net)". F# is a .net language.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, e.g. for Haskell there are a few embedded DSLs for type checked SQL generation:

- query comprehensions
- [DSH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/DSH)

Recall that LINQ was inspired by [monad comprehensions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683506/are-there-any-connections-between-haskell-and-linq)

Comment: I have been reading the DSH paper and is just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Haskell there is such thing already - [Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like persistent is less expressive however. I haven't seen any join/group by/distict/projection operator. Not sure if the reason is the the library itself, or lack of support from quoiting in Haskell.

Comment: @Olmo Haskell supports [quoting](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation).