# Did XQuery give birth to LINQ?

Tags: linq, xquery

I was reading up on XQuery (from this link: [`[1]`](http://www.altova.com/mobiletogether/xpath-intro.html)). And LINQ (more accurately Query Expressions) seems to be an almost carbon-copy of it. So I'm wondering if Microsoft actually just copied XQuery and threw some syntactic sugar over it. I would say inspired but it doesn't seem strong enough a description.

[An example:](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2006/04/linq-vs-xquery.html)

```
// LINQ - Query Expression
var winners = from r in racers
   where r.Wins > 3
   orderby r.Wins descending
   select r;

// XQuery
for $racer in doc("racers.xml")/Racers/Racer
  where $racer/Wins > 3
  order by $racer/Wins descending
  return $racer
```

Comment: LINQ is also very similar to SQL, what a coincidence (?)

Comment: here's a [2005 video about linq](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/scobleizer/Anders-Hejlsberg-LINQ) when it was being worked on .  [According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) XQuery became a W3C Recommendation on January 23, 2007 so I'm guessing probably not

Comment: @ConradFrix - Actually I just read a wikipedia article that says that a book on XQuery was published in 2004. And here's a link to it: http://www.amazon.com/XQuery-The-XML-Query-Language/dp/0321165810

Comment: @dotnetN00b actually I was considering backing off of that comment anyway. One of the other links on the wiki article is to a book titled [XQuery from the Experts: A Guide to the W3C XML Query Language](http://www.amazon.com/XQuery-Experts-Guide-Query-Language/dp/0321180607) that was published in 2003. One of the book's authors, Michael Rys, worked for MS at the time. Unless someone who actually knows said or says one way or another which one influenced which it might be tough to say

Comment: @ConradFrix - your comment led to that small discovery (book link I found). so i thank you for it. I guess someone would have to find out when linq was actually designed.

Answer (score 2):

No, LINQ was not copied from XQuery.

As Eric Lippert indicates in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683716/3225495):

> The design of LINQ query comprehensions was heavily influenced by the design of Haskell. Haskell expert Erik Meijer was on the C# language design committee when we designed LINQ; his insights were very valuable.

Comment: Seems there's a more general functional programming collection querying flavor to them all, as Python list comprehensions and itertools work similarly, from what I have dabbled in.